# MVC AJAX File Uploading - Ceased To Work

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a solution for uploading a file and other data via an AJAX request to an MVC controller.

For a long time, this has been working fine, but today, I've been investigating issues people have been reporting with it, and now it appears to not be functioning at all; I am now getting a "Resource not found" error returned.

If I remove "data: fileData," from the AJAX call, then it is able to resolve the URL, but obviously, there is then no data to process.

Would someone be able to shed any light on why this could stop functioning in this way? I am at a loss to explain this.

### **In Short**:

AJAX call no longer able to resolve controller method URL. No obvious recent changes made to this functionality in repository history.

Thank you,
Matthew.

### **UPDATE**

For the sake of those interested, it turns out that the size of the specific PDF file I was given to test was the culprit all along...This solution still works, and can work for larger files by

### adding the following to the web.config file:

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="10240" />
    <!--This allows larger files to be uploaded (10MB in KB)-->
</system.web>
...
<system.webServer>
    <security>
        <requestFiltering>
            <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="10485760" />
            <!--This allows larger files to be uploaded (10MB in Bytes)-->
        </requestFiltering>
    </security>
</system.webServer>
```

### **END UPDATE**

In-page Javascript:

```
function SaveAttachmentData() {
    var attachmentID = $('#attachmentrecordid').val();
    var servID = $('#servrecordid').val();
    var description = $('#txtattachmentdescription').val();

    // Checking whether FormData is available in browser
    if (window.FormData !== undefined) {

        var fileUpload = $("#attachmentfile").get(0);
        var files = fileUpload.files;

        // Create FormData object
        var fileData = new FormData();

        // Looping over all files and add it to FormData object
        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            fileData.append(files[i].name, files[i]);
        }

        // Adding keys to FormData object
        fileData.append('service_id', servID);
        fileData.append('dataid', attachmentID);
        fileData.append('description', description);

        var validData = true;
        if (!isNormalInteger(servID)){validData = false;}
        if (servID < 1) {validData = false;}
        if (files.length == 0 && $('#attachmentrecordid').val() < 1){validData = false;}

        if (validData){ //All data is valid

                $.ajax({
                    url: '/Service/AttachmentCreate',
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: false, // Not to set any content header
                    processData: false, // Not to process data
                    data: fileData,
                    success: function (result) {
                        ReloadAttachmentTable();
                    },
                    error: function (err) {                            
                        ReloadAttachmentTable();
                    }
                });
            }

        else{
            //Data is not valid
            alert('Invalid data entered!');
            //ShowBannerMessageWarning('Warning!','Invalid data entered!');
        }

    } else {
        alert("FormData is not supported.");
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult AttachmentCreate()
    {
        //Upload file
        string message = "";
        DataModel dm = new DataModel();
        Service.Attachment sa = new Service.Attachment();

        //Get request data
        string description = Request.Form["description"];
        int servid = int.Parse(Request.Form["service_id"]);
        HttpFileCollectionBase files = Request.Files;
        //Only continue if a file was uploaded
        if (files.Count > 0)
        {
            //Get the file
            HttpPostedFileBase file = files[0];
            string fname;
            // Checking for Internet Explorer
            if (Request.Browser.Browser.ToUpper() == "IE" || Request.Browser.Browser.ToUpper() == "INTERNETEXPLORER")
            {
                string[] testfiles = file.FileName.Split(new char[] { '\\' });
                fname = testfiles[testfiles.Length - 1];
            }
            else
            {
                fname = file.FileName;
            }
            //Update attachment properties
            sa.ID = servid;
            sa.Description = description;
            sa.Filename = fname; //Assign fname before the full path is added to it
            //Get full filename from attachment class property
            fname = sa.Filename_Structured;

            // Get the complete folder path and store the file inside it.
            fname = Path.Combine(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AttachmentFolderLocation"].ToString(), fname);
            //Save file to server
            file.SaveAs(fname);

            //Create file attachment record against service
            message = dm.CreateAttachmentData(ref sa);
            message = message == "" ? "Success" : message;
        }
        else { message = "No file uploaded"; }
        return Content(message);
    }
```

Comment: The error is coming from your C# code. I'd suggest stepping through it to figure out exactly what part of the logic is causing the issue

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Rory. The issue is, that the C# code isn't even being reached (unless I remove the data from the AJAX call), so there's nothing for me to step in to.

Comment: When you say you get 'resource not found', is the status code a 404?

Comment: I'm not actually seeing a status code, but the response I'm getting using Firebug is:    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
   Resource not found

<!-- Visual Studio Browser Link -->
<script type="application/json" id="__browserLink_initializationData">
    {"appName":"Chrome","requestId":"b05fab316df7456b97540fb876a093c8"}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:58460/62edc34977204afc8c7b4a5591d36762/browserLink" async="async"></script>
<!-- End Browser Link -->

</body>
</html>

Comment: Can you try this content type: contentType: 'multipart/form-data'

Comment: @Simser This has enabled the AJAX request to reach the controller method, but Request.Form["..."] is returning nulls; just like if I were to remove the "data: ..." portion of the AJAX.

Comment: In addition to the content type change, try replacing AttachmentCreate() with AttachmentCreate(HttpPostedFileBase file). Is file null?

Comment: I imagine that I can make this work again by rewriting the logic to expect the parameters I'm passing in the form, but my concern was that this was working without parameters before, and I was quite pleased when I got it working in this way originally.

Comment: Unfortunately I have no other ideas why this isn't working anymore.

Comment: It's the strangest thing... I guess I'll have to move on to a different solution